# Unexpected side effect in "isExpiryComing" computed property

Tags: vue.js

I tried to make the `nearExpiry` attribute to become TRUE if it is within the range of 30 days. But I hit an error which is `Unexpected side effect in "isExpiryComing" computed property`, is there any way I can overcome this?

I'm not sure how do I use slice at the isExpiryComing computed properties. Is there any workaround for this error?
[image]

```html
<template>
    <div class="container wrapper d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <h1 class="text-info">Ingredients List</h1>

        <ingredients-list class="justify-content-center" 
            v-for="(ingredient,index) in sortedItems"
            :key="index" 
            :index='index' 
            :food-name="ingredient.food" 
            :food-expiry="ingredient.expiryDate"
            :is-expiry="isExpiryComing.nearExpiry"></ingredients-list>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                ingredients: [
                    {
                        food: 'CARROT',
                        expiryDate: '2020-12-12',
                        nearExpiry: false
                    },
                    {
                        food: 'PAPAYA',
                        expiryDate: '2018-1-15',
                        nearExpiry: false
                    },
                    {
                        food: 'ORANGE',
                        expiryDate: '2021-10-13',
                        nearExpiry: false
                    },
                    {
                        food: 'CHICKEN',
                        expiryDate: '2019-4-23',
                        nearExpiry: false
                    },
                    {
                        food: 'MEAT',
                        expiryDate: '2021-5-23',
                        nearExpiry: false
                    },

                ],

            }

        },
        computed: {
            sortedItems() {
                return this.ingredients.slice().sort((a, b) => {
                    return new Date(a.expiryDate) - new Date(b.expiryDate);
                });
            },
            isExpiryComing() {
                const now = new Date().getTime()
                const expiryDate = new Date(this.expiryDate).getTime()

                if (now - expiryDate > (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
                    this.nearExpiry = false
                } else {
                    this.nearExpiry = true
                }
                return this.nearExpiry
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please post the error message?

Comment: Unexpected side effect in "isExpiryComing" computed property  vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties

Comment: where did you define `nearExpiry`?

Comment: It's because you are setting `this.nearExpiry`, which is not what a computed is for (setting a side property).  You'd use a method for that.  Use a local variable for `nearExpiry` instead of `this.nearExpiry`.

Comment: i wan to set a condition which the `nearExpiry` would change to true if the date is more than 30 days, how can i do it to achieve that?

Comment: do you use eslinter?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're chagning another variable inside a computed property, `this.nearExpiry` - your use case doesn't need it.

I assume you want to check the expiration date for every product inside v-for.
I would suggest removing `isExpiryComing` entirely and changing the `sortedItems` to:

```js
                return this.ingredients
                    .slice()
                    .sort((a, b) => {
                        return new Date(a.expiryDate) - new Date(b.expiryDate)
                    })
                    .map((ingredient) => {
                        const now = new Date().getTime()
                        const expiryDate = new Date(ingredient.expiryDate).getTime()

                        return { ...ingredient, nearExpiry: now - expiryDate > 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }
                    })
```

Might be also a good idea to move `const now = new Date().getTime()` higher, to **`data()`**.

Comment: what does the ...ingredient means?

Comment: The last line is basically: For each iteration, return a new object which consists of all the current key:value pairs of **ingredient** (like `food:'CARROT', expiryDate:'2020-12-12', nearExpiry:false`) and add new *nearExpiry* to them.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues I see with this:

- `isExpiryComing` is scoped to your current component (like `ingredients` and `sortedItems`), not to the iteration of your `v-for` (like `ingredient` and `index`).
- Setting to `this.nearExpiry = true` is likely what is causing the error. Computed properties should be [pure-functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), i.e. they should not affect the state (normally this wouldn't be the case, as `this` should be scoped to the function with the method signature you used, but this is Vue so good luck with upholding that). If you want to affect state, you should use a [watched property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html?#Computed-vs-Watched-Property). (and since you are just returning `this.nearExpiry`, why not just make `nearExpiry` a local variable?).

To fix the error, just make `nearExpiry` a local variable instead of a vue-instance variable (`this.nearExpiry`). But, per my first point, that's probably not what you want either. Probably move the computed property to your `ingredients-list` component.